# How to send PZEM-004t measurement module's data which is on Raspberry pie to MongoDB database. Need a step by step procedure

Tags: python-3.x, database, mongodb, backend, fetch-api

How we can send Real time PZEM-004T measurement module data to MongoDB, to save all the real time readings.
Need assistance regarding it, with step-by-step instructions.

Currently we are looking for Backend database setup at the foremost priority.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How is that sensor connected to the pi? Once you figure out how to get the value, you can use PyMongo from a python script to send the measurement to the database. Presumably you will run MongoDB on another machine or in the cloud. Here's an [example](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/technologies/raspberrypi/code-examples/) to get you started.